# HTML5 Animations - Backwards Compatibility

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate, backwards-compatibility

Okay, I Ruled out a lot of fancy CSS3 properties for my website, but I would like to include animations.

The way I have made my animations was by using Adobe Edge PR 4. Unfortunately, I just figured out that the HTML5 animations are not compatible with IE8 (Oh, here I go ranting about IE8 Backwards-Compatibility again... )

How can I Put in a message in place of it, which will only appear in Internet Explorer 8 or lower?

It works in all browsers I have tried, apart from IE8 or Earlier. I do not wish to move to flash, as I would like better mobile device compatibility.

Comment: see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a conditional comment...

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<p>The animations are not supported in your browser.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thenks, That should do it.  :)

Comment: *Update* my conditional comments now prompt users to install ChromeFrame